# Combined Variation Formula Derivation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I'm teaching a pre calculus class and I'm running into this seemingly simple concept that I just can't derive.

So we just went over direct and inverse variation, and have arrived at an example where y is directly proportional to T AND indirectly proportional to V.  Here the book just threw it out there that the formula to use is $y = \frac{kT}{V}$ but I can't seem to understand where this formula came from.

I mean, we have that $y = k_1 T$ and $y = \frac{k_2}{V}$ but where did the $y = \frac{kT}{V}$ come from? I could only obtain such an equation by squaring $y: y^2 = k_1 T \frac{k_2}{V} = \frac{kT}{V}$ for $k = k_1 k_2$.

I feel like I'm missing something very fundamental here...... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Directly proportional to $T$" and "inversely proportional to $V$" both refer to cases **where all other variables are held constant**. Hence in the relation $y=k_1T$, $k_1$ contains an expression with $V$ held constant, and since $V$ is inversely proportional to $y$ we can write $k_1=\frac kV$, which yields the desired expression of $y=\frac{kT}V$. Likewise, we can write $k_2=kT$ for the other relation $y=\frac {k_2}V$ and obtain the same result.

Comment: I see... So essentially it's not really both directly and indirectly proportional since both V and T are variables.